# Unknown CMake command 'get_executable_path'

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ubuntu 22, in ros2 humble, i am building RMF from sources, when i ran colcon build i got the error from rmf_fleet_msgs package
Unknown CMake command 'get_executable_path'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415427/unknown-cmake-command-%27get_executable_path%27/) by [Vignesht.tech](https://answers.ros.org/users/65370/vignesht.tech/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2023-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved by uninstalling ros2 humble completely and reinstalled, now the problem solved. First time maybe ros2 humble not installed properly.

---

Originally posted by [Vignesht.tech](https://answers.ros.org/users/65370/vignesht.tech/) with karma: 16 on 2023-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0